# Disassemble the PDP-8 program

Tags: assembly, disassembly

This is a PDP-8 Program. Kindly can any one disassemble it.

```
Binary representation   Octal Representation
111000000001            7001
010000011100            2034
101000010001            5021
101000010000            5020
```

I want to know what the heck this code is doing.

PS: This is not a homework. I just found this code in a video. There is no explanation about it.

Comment: A good start: http://www.faqs.org/faqs/dec-faq/pdp8/section-3.html

Comment: And here: http://www.cs.uiowa.edu/~jones/pdp8/man/mri.html

Comment: If this is homework, make sure you tag it as such.

Comment: Ah, here we go, this provides a more sanely-formatted version of the OPR instructions: http://landley.net/history/mirror/dec/pdp8faq.html

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
7001         IAC      Increment the accumulator 
2034         ISZ 24 Increment location 0024, skip next instruction if zero 
5021         JMP .-1  Jump back one place 
5020         JMP .-3  Jump back to beginning
```

[Source](http://www.oldcomputers.arcula.co.uk/bpdp82.htm), about halfway down the page is this exact program.

> All this program does is add one to
>   the accumulator, then it counts from 0
>   up to 4096, then it adds another one
>   to the accumulator and so on ... The
>   adding up to 4096 is sufficient delay
>   so that the higher order accumulator
>   lights can be seen to be switching on
>   and off rather than just flickering
>   rapidly.

Comment: +1 for the Disassembly, mentioning the exact source & explanation.